# Return not ending method in c

Tags: c, return

*edit - i figured out the arithmetic error but I still have the return error*

For some reason my program is giving me two errors. First error is that the "return" at the end of each of my methods() are not ending the method and bring me back to main. My second question is at line 23 where pfNum = mainSize/pageSize; is giving me a "SIGFPE, arithmetic exception" not sure why both of these are occuring can anyone help me out?

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Define page table as dynamic structure containing virtual page and page frame 
   and initialize variable as pointer to structure */
struct table{
    int vp;
    int pf;
}*pageTable = NULL;
/* Declare global var's */
int mainSize,pageSize,policy,pfNum;
/**********************************************************************/
void option1(){
/* Declare local var's */
    int k;
/* Prompt for main memory size, page size, and replacement policy */
    printf("Enter main memory size(words): ");
    scanf("%d",&mainSize);
    printf("Enter page size(words/page): ");
    scanf("%d",&pageSize);
    printf("Enter replacement policy(0=LRU, 1=FIFO): ");
    scanf("%d",&policy);
    pfNum = mainSize/pageSize;
/* Allocate and initialize page table based on number of entries */
    pageTable = malloc(pfNum *sizeof(pageTable));
    for(k=0;k<pfNum;k++){
        pageTable[k].vp=-1;
        pageTable[k].pf=k;
    }
return;
}
/**********************************************************************/
void option2(){
/* Declare local var's */
    int va,page,offset,i=0,temp;
/* Prompt for virtual address */
    printf("Enter virtual memory address to access: ");
    scanf("%d",&va);
/* Translate virtual mem addr to virtual page and offset*/
    page = va/pageSize;
    offset = va%pageSize;
/* Check for end of table, unallocated entry, or matched entry in table 
and update table appropriately; while none of three cases, keep looping */

    while(i<pfNum && pageTable[i].vp!=1 && pageTable[i].vp!=page)
        i++;
    if(i<=pfNum){
        int j;
        temp = pageTable[0].pf;
        for(j=1;j<pfNum;j++)
            pageTable[j-1]=pageTable[j];
        pageTable[j].vp=page;
        pageTable[j].pf=temp;
        printf("Page Fault!");
    }
    else if(pageTable[i].vp==-1){
        pageTable[i].vp = page;
        printf("Page fault!");
    }
    else if(pageTable[i].vp==page){
        temp = pageTable[i].pf;
        int l,address;
        for(l=i+1;l<pfNum-1;l++)
            pageTable[l-1]=pageTable[l];
        pageTable[l].vp = page;
        pageTable[l].pf = temp;
        address = (temp*pageSize)+offset;
        printf("Virtual address %d maps to physical address %d",va,address);
    }
 return;
}
 /**********************************************************************/
void option3(){
 /* Declare local var's */
    int u;
    for(u=0;u<pfNum;u++ && pageTable[u].vp!=-1)
        printf("VP %d --> PF %d",pageTable[u].vp,pageTable[u].pf);
 /* Print out each valid virtual page and page frame pair in table */

 return;
}


 /**********************************************************************/
 int main(){
 /* Declare local var's */
    int choice;
 /* Until user quits, print menu of options, prompt for user input, and select     appropriate option */
    printf("/n");
    printf("Virtual memory to Main memory mapping:\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------\n");
    printf("1) Set parameters\n");
    printf("2) Map virtual address\n");
    printf("3) Print page table\n");
    printf("4) Quit\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter Selection: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    printf("\n");
    while(choice!=4){
        if(choice==1)
            option1();
        else if(choice==2){
            option2();
        }
        else if(choice==3)
            option3();
    }
    printf("Goodbye. Have a nice day.");
return 1;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the "return" at the end of each of my methods() are not ending the method and bring me back to main."? You put the `return`s at the **end** of each method - where the method finishes anyways. What exactly do expect those `return` statements to do?

Comment: they program just sits after i make a selection. For selection 1 it keeps asking me the same question over till the SIGFPE arithmetic exception pops up.

Comment: Try using a debugger to see why your methods don't seem to be returning.

Comment: You also only ever set the value of `choice` once, before the `while` loop. You need to input another menu choice every time the loop is run.

Comment: that was it, i place the beginning of the while loop at the wrong place... I should have put it before i started printing the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "SIGFPE, arithmetic exception" exception is most likely caused by division by zero.

Comment: And remove all `return`s from `void`s. They're useless as all of them are at the *end* of a void function. That should do it.

Comment: hmm didnt work.. the program just sits there after i make the selection

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that once you've made your initial choice, nothing changes choice again, so the program goes around the loop, executing your initial choice (possibly doing nothing at all, since you don't validate for zero, negative choices, or values greater than four).  This might give the appearance that your functions "don't return" but actually they do return; they just get called again almost immediately.

You probably need to prompt for a new choice each time around the loop, which suggests a function to prompt and return the choice which you call from a `while` loop.

You have at least one `"/n"` where you probably intended `"\n"`.  Your farewell message is missing its newline; so are a number of other messages (such as the `"Page Fault!"` messages). You don't check that your input functions were successful.  You don't check that the memory allocation was successful.

Your SIGFPE probably comes from division by zero; print the values you're processing before you execute the division.